# Delay start of a CATransition

Tags: ios, caanimation

It's possible to delay the animation of a CATransition? I tried with `startProgress`but it doesn't make any difference.

This is how I'm making the transition:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setDuration:0.25];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pushAnimation"];
```

Comment: Why you want to delay it?

Comment: Because I need to wait for an animation (in another view) to end before I start this animation.

Comment: you may use UIView animation then.

Comment: Actually I can, but UIView animation doesn't have a kCATransitionPush kind animation. I know i could wait to get notified for the other animation to end and then start this, but I wan't to know if is possible to just delay it.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this: http://wangling.me/2011/06/time-warp-in-animation.html
It's a good article about additional timing properties of animatios.

Comment: This works, but the layer will flash black while waits for the delay... Thanks anyway!